# Error handling in protobuf

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am new to protobuf (C++) and try to write first test program with protobuf.
Code is

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "proto/req.pb.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace google::protobuf;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
      std::string s = "asdfasdf";

        auto MyLogHandler = [] (google::protobuf::LogLevel level, const char* filename, int line, const std::string& message)
        {
            std::cout << "message " << message << std::endl;
        };
        google::protobuf::SetLogHandler(MyLogHandler);

        Request req;
        if ( req.ParseFromString(s)){
            cout << "Parse - OK" << endl;
        }else{
               cout << "Parse - ERROR" << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

When program runs - it show only error message, but not any reason about it. How can I get a reason for the error?

Answer (score 8):

There are two reasons Protobuf parsing can fail:

- The input data is missing required fields. In this case the Protobuf library writes a log message describing the problem and then returns false. Your log handler will receive the error message in this case.
- The input data is not a valid Protobuf (it is corrupt, or was never a protobuf in the first place). In this case the Protobuf library simply returns false without any error message. There is really no useful information that the library could provide here. If this happens to you, the best way to debug is to dump the exact bytes right after you serialized the message and right before you parsed it, then look for differences.

Comment: It was not-protobuf message. It is some strange behavior with protobobuf library silently returns false without any notation.

Comment: @Nikolay - Yes, your bogus input data falls into the second category. As I said, the protobuf library doesn't give you any information because there is no useful information to give. `false` means "the data is not a protobuf". That's it. (This is not "silent". "Silent" would be if it returned `true` even when the message is invalid.)

Comment: @KentonVarda There is a third category. a valid protobuf that requires too many recursion to parse. In that case it is possible to parse it by increasing the recursion limit. But since the C++ protobuf library returns no useful error information, a user cannot figure out the reason. BTW, the Rust protobuf library returns the error information correctly. So, one can test with the Rust library to get the error information.

Comment: @zeodtr If you are OK with accepting a larger recursion limit, you should increase the limit before you parse the first time. There's no need to react to this error programmatically. IIRC the library does log a human-readable error message explaining the problem, for debugging purposes.